# hadoop orc table taking only one mapper all the time

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, orc, bigdata

In my current project I am working with Orc files with snappy compression format ,What ever query I run it is running with only one mapper .I tried to configure the mapred.max.split.size and mapred.min.split.size,but is not showing any changes in the number of mappers.The reducer count is good enough ,but as the mapper is a single mapper,The time to run  a simple query like .

select x,max(y) from z group by x ; is taking almost 20 mins to complete the mapper .
Is there any other things I should do to increase the number of mappers.

Please don't tell that to use the partitions or buckets ,As I have used them already in my table.

Comment: Which version of Hive? Using TEZ of MapReduce? How many physical files? ORC strip size? Gathered statistics on table? Does the EXPLAIN plan make sense? Tried with default GZip compression instead? What's the actual partition key, by the way - X, Y, something else? Tried to enforce partition-wise mappers with `select X, max(YY) from (select PART, X, max(Y) as YY from Z group by PART, X) Duh group by X`?

Comment: Hive version-2.3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with tblproperties orc.stripe.size.

The default value for stripe size is 256 MB and technically there is one mapper per one stripe. With decreasing size of single stripe you can increase number of mappers.